# Having trouble with C# arrays and objects

Tags: c#

I come from a JavaScript background, and I'm having trouble understanding C#.

I'm trying to implement an array of objects, like so

**JavaScript**

```js
var objectArray = [];

objectArray[0] = {
    name: "Test",
    text: "Hello!",
    turn: 25
};

objectArray[1] = {
    name: "Test2",
    text: "Hello, the second time!",
    turn: 27
};

....
```

How would I do something like this in C#?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I'm afraid this is not a beginner tutorial site. There are many tutorials online (even videos on e.g. youtube), or good books written. You should start there

Answer (score 2):

So firstly the schema of the object would need to be created as a class.

```
public class YourObjectName 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Turn { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can instantiate a list of this class like so ...

```
var myList = new List<YourObjectName>();
```

If you want to initialise with values you can do ...

```
var myList = new List<YourObjectName>()
{
    {
        Name: "Test",
        Text: "Hello!",
        Turn: 25
    },
    {
        Name: "Test2",
        Text: "Hello, the second time!",
        Turn: 27
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

While something like this is possible [like so](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R4D4Qr):

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        object[] objectArray = new object[]{
            new {
                name = "Test",
                text = "Hello!",
                turn = 25
            },
            new {
                name = "Test2",
                text = "Hello, the second time!",
                turn = 27
            }
        };
        
        foreach (object o in objectArray)
            System.Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
    }
}
```

Producing the following output:

```
{ name = Test, text = Hello!, turn = 25 }
{ name = Test2, text = Hello, the second time!, turn = 27 }
```

It is not common. You'd usually create a class that defines the Structure of the data you want to handle and make an array out of that like

```
ClassName[] array = new ClassName[ArraySize];
```

Read up on classes and inheritance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes).